# how to create view when multiple groups using Mysql

Tags: html, mysql

I am working on a project that I need a report. I want to count on this report  In January 2014, which class of students have entered month of January.       The student's table has only a class number. And the table's table contains all the information.

```
       Group No 1. month and year.

       Group No 2. Class

       My STD Table
```

+--------+----------+-----------------+----------------+------------+
| STD_ID | STD_name | Admission_Month | Admission_year | Class_Code |
+--------+----------+-----------------+----------------+------------+
| 01     |  ABC     | January         |  2017          | 1          |
+--------+----------+-----------------+----------------+------------+
| 02     | DEF      | January         |  2017          | 2          |
+--------+----------+-----------------+----------------+------------+
|03      | GHI      | February        |  2017           | 1          |
+--------+----------+-----------------+----------------+------------+

I Need this Output

```
+--------+----------+-----------------+----------------+
| Month  | Year     | Class           | Count_Student  |
+--------+----------+-----------------+----------------+
|January | 2017     |     01          |    01          |
+--------+----------+-----------------+----------------+
|January | 2017     |     02          |    01          |
+--------+----------+-----------------+----------------+
|February| 2014     |     01          |    01          | 
+--------+----------+-----------------+----------------+
```

**Anyone help me please**

Comment: Please post your table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution for your problem :

Table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE student ( 
  STD_ID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  STd_name varchar(25),
  Admission_Month varchar(25),
  Admission_year varchar(25),
  Class_Code varchar(25),
  std_Status varchar(25),
  PRIMARY KEY (STD_ID) ) #ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE CLASS ( 
  Class_Code MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Class_name varchar(25),
  CLass_Courcess varchar(25),
PRIMARY KEY (Class_Code) ) 
#ENGINE=MyISAM;


INSERT INTO student (STd_name, Admission_Month, Admission_year, Class_Code,std_Status)
VALUES ("ABC","January","2017","1","On"),
       ("DEF","January","2017","1","On"),
       ("GHI","February","2017","2","Off"),
       ("ADFDBC","MARCH","2017","1","On");


INSERT INTO CLASS (Class_name,CLass_Courcess)
VALUES("DIV A","MBA"),("DIV B","MTECH")
```

Query :

```
    SELECT Admission_Month as Month, Admission_year as Year, Class_name as Class, 
    (SELECT COUNT(s_on.STD_ID) FROM student as s_on WHERE s_on.Admission_Month = student.Admission_Month AND s_on.Admission_year = student.Admission_year AND s_on.Class_Code = student.Class_Code AND s_on.std_Status ="On") as status_on, 
    (SELECT COUNT(s_on.STD_ID) FROM student as s_on WHERE s_on.Admission_Month = student.Admission_Month AND s_on.Admission_year = student.Admission_year AND s_on.Class_Code = student.Class_Code AND s_on.std_Status ="Off") as status_off
    FROM student
    LEFT JOIN class ON class.Class_Code = student.Class_Code
    GROUP BY Admission_Month,Admission_year
```

and also you can refer [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1709dc/1)

I hope it will help.